# Multiple circular image with green border as map pin on Xamarin forms ,Xamarin android Xamarin IOS

Tags: xamarin, maps

I have an image which should have circular border around it .
Please help I am struggling from weeks now

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution 1:

You can put the image in a **Frame** , and set the **CornerRadius** and **BorderColor** .

```
<Frame CornerRadius="50" Padding="0" BorderColor="Green" HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100">
    <Image Source="xxx.png" />
</Frame>
```

#### Solution 2:

You can use  `Custom Renderer` in xamarin.forms

**in iOS**

```
//...
using xxx;
using xxx.iOS;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyImage), typeof(MyImageRenderer))]
namespace xxx.iOS
{
  public class MyImageRenderer:ImageRenderer
  {
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Image> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control != null)
        {
            Control.Layer.MasksToBounds = true;
            Control.Layer.CornerRadius = 50;  //set the rounded corner
            Control.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.Green.CGColor;
            Control.Layer.BorderWidth = 1;
        }
    }
 }
}
```

**in Android**

creat a xml file in the folder **Resource->drawable** `image_view_style.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item>
   <shape
     android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid
      android:color="#00ff00" />
    <corners
      android:radius="50dp" />
    <stroke
      android:width="1dp"
      android:color="#00ff00" />
   </shape>
</item>
```

```
using Android.Support.V4.Content.Res;
using xxx;
using xxx.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyImage), typeof(MyImageRenderer))]
namespace xxx.Droid
{
 public class MyImageRenderer:ImageRenderer
 {
   public MyAndriodEntry(Context context):base(context)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Image> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if(Control!=null)
        {
           Control.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.image_view_style);
        }

    }
  }
}
```

**in Forms**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace xxx
{
 public class MyImage : Image
 {
    public MyImage()
    {

    }
 }
}
```